# Use of undeclared identifier 'Intercom' in AppDelegate.m - react-native-intercom

Tags: ios, react-native, intercom, intercom.js, intercom-ios

I am using `react-native-intercom` to manage Intercom in my app. I have installed the Intercom iOS SDK using CocoaPods, and linked the `react-native-intercom`. But Build failed with error `Use of undeclared identifier 'Intercom' in AppDelegate.m - react-native-intercom`

```
steps 1 (Install and Link Intercom)

npm install react-native-intercom
react-native link react-native-intercom

step 2 (Import Intercom in AppDelegate.m)
#import "Intercom/intercom.h"


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[Intercom setApiKey:@"myApiKey" forAppId:@"myAppId"];
[Intercom registerUnidentifiedUser];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
[Intercom setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using react-native and fixed this issue by changing `intercom` into `Intercom`.

> #import "Intercom/Intercom.h"

use `#import "Intercom/Intercom.h"` instead of `#import "Intercom/intercom.h"` in `AppDelegate.m` file

If you go into the framework's Headers folder in your workspace `(Workspace -> Intercom.framework -> Headers)` you will see the `Intercom.h` file.